# How to add precision to a sql view?

Tags: mysql, precision

I have created mySQL view. Now I want to add upto 2-digit decimal point precision and if possible % symbol too. Please point me in the right direction.

One of the queries from the view is:

```
SELECT 
    budget.INITIAL_BUDGET / (budget.ACTUAL_SPENT + budget.PROJECT_EAC) * 100 AS `PROJECT_ESTIMATE_ACCURACY`
FROM budget;
```

For example- above query gives output as 98.564732. I want the value to be shown as "98.56%"
in the view.

Comment: can you please be a bit more clear on your question and give some sample data for the question ?

Comment: And what have you tried? A quick scan through the MySQL documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/func-op-summary-ref.html) provides a complete list of available functions. Among these, FORMAT can help with the decimals... and CONCAT can help with the percent sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate answer for my question is as follows-

```
Select  CONCAT(ROUND((budget. PQ_ESTIMATE/(budget.ACTUAL_SPENT + budget.PROJECT_EAC))*100,2),'%') AS PROJECT_QUOTATION_ESTIMATE_ACCURACY FROM budget;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Truncate:

```
SELECT 
    TRUNCATE(budget.INITIAL_BUDGET / 
    (budget.ACTUAL_SPENT + budget.PROJECT_EAC) * 100,2) AS `PROJECT_ESTIMATE_ACCURACY`
FROM budget;
```

or

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(budget.INITIAL_BUDGET / 
    (budget.ACTUAL_SPENT + budget.PROJECT_EAC) * 100,2) AS `PROJECT_ESTIMATE_ACCURACY`
FROM budget;
```

Comment: ROUND would be better i guess.

Comment: I got it. Appreciate your time all of you. Thanks a lot.